To find union of two sorted arrays
In the problem, we have to find union of two arrays sorted in non-decreasing order.
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> findUnion(vector<int>&a,vector<int>&b) {
    vector<int>v;
    int i(0); int j(0);
    while (i<a.size() && j<b.size()) {
        if (a[i]<b[j]) {
            v.push_back(a[i]);
            while (a[i+1]==a[i]) i++;
            i++;
        }
        else if (a[i]>b[j]) {
            v.push_back(b[j]);
            while (b[j+1]==b[j]) j++;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            v.push_back(a[i]);
            while (a[i+1]==a[i]) i++;
            i++;
            while (b[j+1]==b[j]) j++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (i<a.size()) {      //I
        v.push_back(a[i]);
        while (a[i+1]==a[i]) i++;
        i++;
    }
    if (j<b.size()) {           //II
        v.push_back(b[j]);
        while (b[j+1]==b[j]) j++;
        j++;
    }
    return v;
}
int main() {
    vector<int>a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    vector<int>b={2,3,4,4,5,11,12};
    vector<int>v=findUnion(a,b);
    for (auto it:v) {
        cout<<it<<" ";
    }
}

I was getting
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

as the output instead of:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

But when I change the input array a as
a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13}

and b remains same, I get output as
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

which is the desired output.
So basically if array a is getting exhausted first, then I am not getting the last element of b. If in the commented lines I and II, if is changed to while, it works fine. So please tell why

Side note : do not use either of those #include<bits/stdc++.h> and using namespace std;

you tually can "cheat" and decided which array is first and which second, so you woldn't need two appraoches

Another side note: unless you're writing findUnion for the fun of doing so, just use std::set_union.

Why not use std::set_union()?

if (i<a.size()) {      //I
    v.push_back(a[i]);
    while (a[i+1]==a[i]) i++;
    i++;
}

should be
while (i<a.size()) {      //I
    v.push_back(a[i]);
    i++;
}

and the same change for the j loop.
If you have reached the end of one vector then you simply want to copy over the rest of the other vector.
Your loop is wrong because, apart from anything else, it tests a[i+1] when there is no guarantee that i+1 is a valid index for the vector.

Dealing with the i+1 issue: I would suggest eliminating duplicates in each input vector at the beginning.

Can you use std::set?  It becomes much easier and more efficient:
#include <vector>
#include <set>

vector<int> findUnion(vector<int>&a,vector<int>&b) {

    std::set<int> s;
    vector<int> result;
    for (int i : a) {s.insert(i);}
    for (int j : b) {s.insert(j);}
    for (auto itor = s.begin(); while itor != s.end(); itor++) {
        result.push_back(*itor);
    }
    return result;
}

And even without set, there's an even faster implementation that takes advantage of the fact that your two input vectors are already sorted:
vector<int> findUnion(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) {

    vector<int> result;

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while (i < a.size() || j < b.size())
    {
        bool useLeft;
        if (i < a.size() && j < b.size()) {
            useLeft = a[i] < b[j];
        }
        else {
            useLeft = (i < a.size());
        }

        int value = useLeft ? a[i] : b[j];
        bool duplicate = ((result.size() != 0) && (result[result.size() - 1] == value));

        if (!duplicate) {
            result.push_back(value);
        }
        if (useLeft) {
            i++;
        }
        else {
            j++; 
        };
    }
    return result;

}


Since std::set is ordered and has reasonable insert complexity (O(n log(n)). So I just would use it. Also note : reusing tested code e.g. standard library code reduces the chance for bugs (make it work first optimize only if needed):
#include <vector>
#include <set>

// set is an ordered set and will even work for non-sorted vectors in O(n log(n)) 
// see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set
// no reason to return a vector, though that should be easy too `return std::vector<int>{result.begin(), result.end()};`

std::set<int> FindUnion(const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs)
{
    std::set<int> result{ lhs.begin(), lhs.end() };
    result.insert(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    return result;
}

If you need a vector you can just construct one from the set.
Small added bonus, the input vectors don't even need to be sorted (the sorting would have taken O(n log(n)) time too)

Speaking of standard library code: std::set_union

@JaMiT Thanks, I somehow missed that algorithm up till now ;)
